# Is there any description for Simu5G files

Tags: networking, omnet++

in Simu5G folder there are many scenarios (NR, multicell, emulation, d2d ,...etc)
is there any pdf or videos that describes these scenarios

Answer (score 0):

According to the official website: [Sim5G Website](http://simu5g.org/guides.html),
the basic usage guides are still to be produced (but I guess you already checked that). Considering that the same authors have also developed the LTE framework, maybe the old guides might help: [SimuLTE](https://simulte.com/guides.html)

I found interesting the recordings from last OMNeT++ summit though. You could have a look. The guys of Simu5G are also there, you could get an idea of how they are using the framework. [Last summit.](https://summit.omnetpp.org/2021/index.html)

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations and guidelines.